# How to stop showing recent files (security issue)

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint, when I click on a users profile I can view their recent files which is a security risk.

How can I disable this from happening?

I want users to be able to click on other users to see their contact details but not show their recent files and activity.

Answer (score 1):

We can control this setting from the **user profile card** settings in Office 365. However, if we still allow to show the recent files, user can see the files of others which they have access to otherwise can not, so this does not break the security rules.

Please read the below MSDN article, how profile cards work in SharePoint :

[Profile cards in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/profile-cards-in-office-365-e80f931f-5fc4-4a59-ba6e-c1e35a85b501?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)